# Editing ConstraintLayout xml is super slow

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I'm working my project and I got some issue.
My project layout type is mostly composed of  `constraintLayout`.

Every time I drag widgets from a certain moment, I get a tremendous amount of lag.
I tried to do it. But I googled because I could not do it anymore.
It's so hard. 
So, I got this.

Im using this for my optimize file in Android directory.
-Xmx4096
-Xmx16g

but it`s not working I think.

My CPU is i7 `6700K`
and
My RAM is 32GB.

Why is this super slow to fix some editing?
Is `ConstraintLayout` much heavier than `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout`?

Comment: Can you post your layout xml here

Comment: It's a mess because it's made for testing now. just some simple buttons, some simple circles and one picture and gradient.xml used for backgroundColor.

Comment: Why do you need multiple `constraintlayout`s? With so few views one single `constraintlayout` should be more than enough. Post your XML code for review by the community.

Answer (score 2):

There are three things you shall try to improve the performance of ConstraintLayout usage:

You can increase virtual machine's heap size for Android Studio: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html#adjusting_heap_size

You can toggle the design surface to only blueprint mode: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/layout-editor.html#change-appearance

You can check that you're using the latest version of the Constraint Layout library v1.0.2: https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/03/constraintlayout-102-is-now-available.html

Comment: Yeah, I did all of this. I think

Comment: In such case I can only recommend you switch over to RelativeLayout. I've tried getting used to ConstraintLayout which comes by default in AndroidStudio since 2017, yet I don't find it as convenient as RL or LL.

Comment: Okay, you think ConstraintLayout is much heavier than RelativeLayout or LinearLayout?

Comment: No, I didn't had such a problem on my setup, yet I found it not as intuitive and user friendly.

Comment: I tried Constraint Layout in a part of my project  and it is rendering super slow ?? Are there any specific things that we have to keep in mind while using Constraint layout ??